# How to POST data to an Array in API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following API

```
{
  "author": [],
  "categories": [],
  "_id": "62ff04704bcdbd99716e0cc4",
  "kind": "books",
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Java",
      "author": [
        "John",
        "Peter"
      ],
      "publisher": "North Publishers",
      "publishedDate": "12 Sep 2021",
      "description": "Learn Java",
      "pageCount": 286,
      "printType": "PaperBack",
      "categories": [
        "Programming",
        "Java"
      ],
      "language": "English",
      "price": 1856
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to send a POST request which will add data in "Items" array in the above API

I have the following code in my schema.js

```
const {Schema, default:mongoose} = require('mongoose');
const bookSchema = new Schema([{
       kind:String,
       title:String,
       author:[String],
       publisher:String,
       publishedDate:String,
       description:String,
       pageCount:Number,
       printType:String,
       categories:[String],
       language:String,
       price:Number,
}]);
const ItemSchema = new Schema([{
       items:[bookSchema]
}])
const book = mongoose.model('book',ItemSchema);
module.exports = book;
```

I have the following code in my routes.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const BookSchema = require('./schema');

app.post('/books', async (req,resp)=>{
   await BookSchema.find({items:'[ ]',function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        data.push(req.query)
    }
   }});
   resp.status(200).send("Success")
```

But i cannot add the data from req.query to the "Items" array using this method

Can anyone tell me the right way of doing this

Comment: It looks like `BookSchema.find` does not return a promise, since it uses a callback function, so `await BookSchema.find` may not work. Try putting the `resp.status` inside the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the data that you are pushing in the `req.query`? Can you show me how you pass the data when you call the API?

In general, the data of POST method should be in the body `req.body`, something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const BookSchema = require('./schema');

app.post('/books', async (req,resp)=>{
   await BookSchema.find({items:'[ ]',function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        data.push(req.body)
    }
   }});
   resp.status(200).send("Success")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i was not able to convey my query properly. Actually i should have used the PUT request to update the array data but i was foolishly using POST request. Thanks for the response